# error al concatenar en un case en sql server

Tags: sql

intente hacer de esta forma:
ya que si ejecuto solo la consulta que seria esta si me sale :

```
(SELECT concat('BIGV-',cast(SUM(LINETOTAL) as varchar(50))) FROM INV1 WHERE DOCENTRY=49386)
```

pero cuando la intento hacer en un case  me bota error:
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'BIGV-254.410000' to data type int.

```
    select 
cast((SELECT TOP 1 CASE
WHEN DOCCUR='S/' AND V4.STCCODE='IGV' THEN
(SELECT concat('BIGV-',cast(SUM(LINETOTAL) as varchar(50))) FROM INV1 WHERE DOCENTRY=49386)
WHEN DOCCUR='US$' AND V4.STCCODE='IGV' THEN
(SELECT concat('BIGV-',cast(SUM(TOTALSUMSY) as varchar(50))) FROM INV1 WHERE DOCENTRY=49386)
ELSE 0 END
FROM INV4 V4 WHERE V4.DOCENTRY=49386)as varchar(20)) from oinv inv where DOCENTRY=49386
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que veo, es que cada `WHEN` del `CASE` retorna un `VARCHAR` sin embargo el `ELSE` esta retornando un valor numérico, seguramente el motor, debido a esto, espera un valor numérico para todo el `CASE`, de ahí el error de conversión. La solución podría ser simplemente retornar un `VARCHAR` reemplazando:

```
ELSE 0
```

por:

```
ELSE '0'
```

Comment: gracias. no sabes como sufri por ese error

Comment: @DannyloRamos, me alegro que te haya servido. Saludos.